# .Net Framework Data Provider for SqlServer (Layer2) not showing existing, modified, or deleted items from List

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list

I am trying to connect a Sharepoint list to SQL Server Management Studio using the .Net Framework Data Provider for SqlServer connection (Layer2).  I only want items from the Sharepoint list to push to the table (e.g. I do not want the data source to update the list)

The mapping and everything is validated, but the table is not updating as expected. New items that are added to the list show in my table, but the existing items that were created prior to the connection are not showing. Also items that are modified or deleted are not reflected (For example, I added a new item to the list. Item shows in data table. I then delete the item. Item is not deleted from the list).

Does anybody know of any settings or bugs/defects that might be causing this? Using Sharepoint 2013.

I have done this for several lists in the past using this same select statement and they behave as expected. The code in the Select is as follows:

```
Select * from [DatabaseName].[Fact].[TableName]
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you tried?

Comment: Added to the original question